# Django Add Toggle Button

Tags: django, django-models

I need to add a toggle button as I have two fields for a blog post `is_draft` and `is_published`.

As only one of them should be true at once, how can I toggle between them?

Comment: I feel like this should be 1 field, is_published and it should be a boolean field. why do you need 2?

Comment: Okay, yes I can change how things look in Django Form for better user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Nathan Smith said.

But, if you want to enforce this kind of rules, the best place to do so is inside the model's save method. See an example below:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    is_published = models.BooleanField()
    is_draft = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # apply the rules, change the data, etc
        if self.is_published:
            self.draft = False
        if self.draft:
            self.published = False
        # call the actual save method
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks. It saved a lot of efforts and I realized the power of save.